# val cannot be reassigned while trying to update Polyline

Tags: android, kotlin

In the code below I get an error `Val cannot be reassigned`,  I dont know how can I recreate the object ? i am new to kotlin and I am just trying to update a code that i found somewhere... trying to understand how to modify it.

I understand it is final and it is being called from another class like this

another class

```
 val polyLine = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road)

PanRoad = newRoad(
    polyLine = polyLine,
    colorRoad = colorRoad,
    roadWidth = roadWidth,
    showPoiMarker = showPoiMarker,
    listInterestPoints = listInterestPoints,
)
```

I tried changin it to val to var like this `var polyLine = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road)` still nothing.

Below is the class that is giving errors

```
private fun newRoad(
        polyLine: Polyline,
        colorRoad: Int?,
        showPoiMarker: Boolean,
        listInterestPoints: List<GeoPoint>,
        roadWidth: Float,
        bitmapIcon: Bitmap? = null,
    ): PanRoad {
        print(message = "pannam createRoad called")

        polyLine.setOnClickListener { _, _, eventPos ->
            methodChannel.invokeMethod("receiveSinglePress", eventPos?.toHashMap())
            true
        }
        /// set polyline color

        val polygonPaint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.BLUE
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }

        val outlinerPaint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.DKGRAY
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeWidth = 2f
        }

        polyLine.outlinePaint = Paint().apply {
            color = colorRoad ?: Color.GREEN
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeWidth = 2f
            strokeCap = Cap.ROUND
            strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        }


        val iconsRoads = customRoadMarkerIcon
        when {
            (iconsRoads.isEmpty() && bitmapIcon != null) -> {
                iconsRoads[Constants.STARTPOSITIONROAD] = bitmapIcon
                iconsRoads[Constants.MIDDLEPOSITIONROAD] = bitmapIcon
                iconsRoads[Constants.ENDPOSITIONROAD] = bitmapIcon
            }
            iconsRoads.isNotEmpty() && bitmapIcon != null -> {
                iconsRoads[Constants.MIDDLEPOSITIONROAD] = bitmapIcon
                if (!iconsRoads.containsKey(Constants.STARTPOSITIONROAD)) {
                    iconsRoads[Constants.STARTPOSITIONROAD] = bitmapIcon
                }
                if (!iconsRoads.containsKey(Constants.ENDPOSITIONROAD)) {
                    iconsRoads[Constants.ENDPOSITIONROAD] = bitmapIcon
                }
            }
        }
        val PanRoad = PanRoad(
            context,
            map!!,
            interestPoint = if (showPoiMarker) listInterestPoints else emptyList(),
            showInterestPoints = showPoiMarker
        )

        PanRoad.let { roadF ->
            if (showPoiMarker) {
                roadF.markersIcons = iconsRoads
            }
            polyLine.outlinePaint.strokeWidth = roadWidth

            roadF.road = polyLine


            folderRoad.items.add(roadF)
        }

        return PanRoad
    }
```

The error occurs at `polyLine.outlinePaint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `Polyline` class you're working with is from `org.osmdroid.views.overlay`, which only provides a `getOutlinePaint` as can be seen in its [JavaDoc](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polyline.html). However, there is no `setOutlinePaint`. From Kotlins point of view `outlinePaint` is therefore a `val` which cannot be reassigned.

It think instead of reassigning the `outlinePaint` field you instead want to retrieve a reference to the `Paint` object stored in the field and modify it directly. Something like the following might work, however I'm unable to verify this at the moment.

```kotlin
val outlinePaint = polyLine.outlinePaint

outlinePaint.color = Color.GREEM
outlinePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
```

or if using `apply` is preferred

```kotlin
polyLine.outlinePaint.apply {
  color = Color.GREEM
  style = Paint.Style.STROKE
}
```

Comment: i get the error `Unresolved reference: polyline`

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, @Pannam. Of course it has to be `polyLine` instead of `polyline` based on your code.